# pgfplots - Proportional axis ticks and terminating grid lines at axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

I want to have grid lines in my graph that end at the x and y axis and do not carry over to the sides. If I turn gridlines on it seems like it fills in past the edges. I'd also like to have the graph start at 0 and have intervals that make sense between each tick on the axis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\documentclas{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=center,
grid=both,
scale only axis=true,
ymin=0,
xmin=0,
xtick={0,2,4,6,8,10,12},
legend pos=outer north east,
clip = true,
clip mode=individual,
axis lines=middle,
title=Voltage \& Current,
ylabel=Current,
xlabel=Voltage,
scaled ticks=false,
enlargelimits=0.2,
]
\addplot[opacity=.5,
   only marks,
   mark=triangle*,
   red
]
table {
x y 
4.025 0.00071 
6.042 0.00107 
7.94 0.00140 
9.98 0.00177 
12 0.00214 
};


\addplot [opacity=.5] table[
y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}] % compute a linear regression from the input table
{
X Y
4.025 0.000706862
6.042 0.001067945
7.94 0.001407724
9.98 0.001772924
12 0.002134544
};
\legend{Voltage,$y=0.00017902x$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you not want to have `enlargelimits=0.2`!? Could you show what you wish with a hand drawing?

Comment: I would like the axis to cross as they are and remove the grid lines beyond the axis and clearly start the graph at 0.

Comment: Then remove `enlargelimits=0.2`

Comment: I did that and it moves the axis back to the edges and creates a square looking graph. I want the axis to cross and extend beyond each other as they do in the above image. I want to remove the grid lines beyond the axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want!? -adjust the numbers to your liking:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
grid=both,
%scale only axis=true,
ymin=0,
xmin=0,
xtick={0,2,4,6,8,10,12},
legend pos=outer north east,
clip mode=individual,
axis lines=middle,
title=Voltage \& Current,
ylabel=Current,
xlabel=Voltage,
scaled ticks=false,
%enlargelimits=0.2,
x axis line style={shorten >=-35pt, shorten <=-35pt},
x label style={xshift=35pt},
y axis line style={shorten >=0pt, shorten <=-35pt},
y label style={yshift=-5pt},
]
\addplot[
opacity=.5,
only marks,
mark=triangle*,
red
] table {
x y 
4.025 0.00071 
6.042 0.00107 
7.94 0.00140 
9.98 0.00177 
12 0.00214 
};

\addplot [opacity=.5] table[
y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}] % compute a linear regression from the input table
{
X Y
4.025 0.000706862
6.042 0.001067945
7.94 0.001407724
9.98 0.001772924
12 0.002134544
};
\legend{Voltage,$y=0.00017902x$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with extended axis]

Comment: Yes. This is what I'm looking for, but I don't want the line to be crammed over to the top right. I added another tick mark with `xtick={0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14},` and the 14 doesn't appear. How do I get the line away from the top right edge?

Comment: Do you want the option: `xmax=14`?

Comment: Yes! That did it thank you. ``ymin=0, ymax=.0025,
xmin=0, xmax=14,``

Comment: Also - no need to set the ticks manually, if you want them evenly spaced - use `xtick distance=2`